# No Manifest detected

Tags: android, web, mobile, progressive-web-apps

I am trying to build a progressive web app. It's in a very basic stage. I have added a manifest.json file. But when I am inspecting it using audit/application tab, that manifest is not available. You can check my current progress from this website(https://pwa-ict1.firebaseapp.com/).

FYI
 1. I have added  in index.html
 2. have created a manifest.json file in root & have written all the necessary code inside it.

Please check attached image for more detail about my audit report.

What should I do now to make it workable?[image]

Comment: Working fine for me - try clearing out your browser cache and emptying out everything using the application tab 99-100-96-100-89 in Chrome Canary.

Comment: Note: Installing Chrome Canary is great for testing your PWA. You can keep cleaning out your browser cache without losing sites you may have open in regular chrome.

Comment: now it's working after inserting service worker's script with it